# Downloading BLOB file has no data

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, blob

I'm trying to download BLOB data from MySQL, but all I can get is a file with 1 KB size.
I've got a table which contains checkboxes, and I'm looking for the checked ones. The values are the IDs.
This is the code:

```
public class FileDownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        DBConnection DBC = new DBConnection();
        Connection con = DBC.connection();
        String[] checkBoxValues = request.getParameterValues("files");

        for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxValues.length; i++) {
            String fileDL = "select * from uploads where file_id='"+checkBoxValues[i]+"'";
            try {
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(fileDL);
                while(rs.next()){
                    String fileName = rs.getString("file_name");
                    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("file");
                    InputStream input = blob.getBinaryStream();

                    int fileSize = (int) blob.length();
                    System.out.println(fileSize);

                    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
                    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fileName);

                    if (mimeType == null) {        
                        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
                    }

                    response.setContentType(mimeType);
                    response.setContentLength(fileSize);
                    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName);
                    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                    OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead = -1;

                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    input.close();
                    output.close();         
                    }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileDownloadServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I have no idea where I went wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
```

always uses the same offset. You are never really advancing in your resulting stream. You'd have to increment your offset by  `bytesRead`

**EDIT: Explanation**

You are using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29
This method writes the bytes in your `buffer` to the outputstream, starting at position 0.
Now, in the next iteration, you read the next 4k bytes and again write it to the outputstream. But your offset hasn't changed, so you are **not appending** the new buffer-content but overwriting the previsously written bytes, because you said to write from position 0 again. Therefor, you need to advance the offset by the same amount of bytes you have previously written.

**EDIT: Spoiler**

So here's the spoiler:

```
int bytesRead = -1;
int offset = 0;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, offset, bytesRead);
    offset += bytesRead;
}
```

Not tested.

Additionally, why do you want to write in 4k chunks?
Why not just

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
    output.write(buffer);
}
```

Comment: First: do you understand the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I do, would you explain?

Comment: Ok, added an explanation. Let me know if this is still unclear

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's clear now. I changed my code by your suggestions, but I've still got this problem. Maybe I messed up at the uploading?

Comment: Could you provide the current code? Additionally, count the bytes you are writing so you can verifiy your expectations. Also, try to setup a testcase where you write the result to the filesystem to actually test this without the overhead of the whole servlet stuff. That way, you can try to narrow down the error. I.e. write a simple test class that reads the blob and writes it to the FS.

Comment: I debugged the code, and it never goes into the while((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) loop. I don't really see why tho.

Comment: Did you actually try the other solution? You also didn't answer to why you need to write in 4k chunks. Did you setup a simple class for a testcase? What does "never goes into the while" mean? It parses the while and skips the body?

Comment: Actually, by looking at it your read seems flawed too. I'll add another explanation for this.

Comment: Since I have no experience in working with Blob files, I was looking for tutorials, and I got my ideas from this one: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-to-download-file-from-database. I'm about to write a class to test it. And yes, it checks the statement and skips the body.